# Different Cloud Messaging services for different product flavors

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-productflavors

For example I am having two product flavors say A and B.
I want to implement FCM in A and GCM in B.
Is that possible? and Why?

Comment: While it is possible, I'm curious, why would you want to do that?

Comment: @JenPerson because I am having two different projects with same basic functionalities.. but one is having FCM and another one is having GCM. The one with GCM is using very old GCM (they're using GCM.jar and old pattern.. so there is no google-services.json file).. and the back-end also setup GCM with old fashioned pattern (so there is no way I can upgrade that GCM to FCM)

Comment: and if I change/bug-fix in FCM's project.. I have to make those changes in GCM's project also.. so I'm trying to add GCM's project as build flavor

Answer (score 0):

Yes, This is possible by defining package id and also different google-services.json file for both flower
Like

I have one flavor A and I create Directory A for that then put google-services.json file inside of A directory

In same as above put another project google-services.json file in another product flavor directory.